# SQL query: select everything from 2 tables and if filename not exists display No files

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: Issues and Attachement

Issue table contains 10 records and has the following design

```
IssueId | IssueName | IssueDate | IssueDescription
```

Attachement contains 5 records table has the following desin

```
IDAttachement | Filename | IssueID
```

I want to select everything from the 2 tables total 10 records as the following if filename not exists display No files

```
IssueID       IssueName        Filename

1             Issue1           file1

2             Issue2           Nofile

3             Issue3           Nofile

4             Issue4           Nofile

5             Issue5           Nofile

6             Issue  6         file6

7             Issue 7          file 7

8               Issue 8          file 8

9               Issue 9          file 9

10            Issue 10        Nofile
```

please help me to display Nofile if there was no attachement for the issue

I need the SQL select Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i.IssueID,i.IssueName, COALESCE (a.Filename,'Nofile') Filename
FROM Issue i
LEFT JOIN Attachement a ON i.IssueID = a.IssueID
```

Comment: COALESCE return's the first non null value, so in case the join return's null in the filename, 'Nofile' value will be returned

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IssueID, IssueName, Filename
       FROM Issues JOIN Attachement ON (Issues.IssueId = Attachement.IssueID);
```

If you were to rename your ID fields so they are both called `IssueId`, you can do even better:

```
SELECT IssueId, IssueName, Filename
       FROM Issues JOIN Attachement USING(IssueId);
```

If you want to include issues for which no attachment record exists at all (rather than one with empty "Filename" field), say `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT OUTER JOIN is what you are looking for. Code is approximate although case sensitivity mayr may not be a factor in your RDBMS

```
SELECT
    I.IssueID
,   I.IssueName
,   coalesce(A.FileName, 'NoFile') AS FileName
FROM
    ISSUES I
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Attachement A
        ON A.IssueID = I.IssueId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.IssueID,i.IssueName,
(case when a.FileName then a.FileName else "NO FILE" end)
FROM Issue i LEFT JOIN Attachement a ON i.IssueID = a.IssueID
```